# MS Excel - Removing All Spaces then comparing the two cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to keep the code to just one cell. I want to remove all the spaces and then compare the left 5 characters to another cell.

I have this

```
=LEFT(A1,5)=LEFT(B1,5)
```

And I have this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", "")
```

I want to combine the two but can't get it right.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")*LEFT(A1,5)=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")LEFT(B1,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the return value of the `SUBSTITUTE` function as the input for the `LEFT` function.

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", ""),5)=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""),5)`

What this does is that it removes the spaces from the value of the cell before it puts it through the `LEFT` function.

Answer (score 0):

you mean it like this?

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),5)=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""),5)
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Paul if this answers your question feel free to accept this answer.